# What is this "Of Date" in VB?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have a function which excepts a string and Of Date is passed. 
What is that?

```
myfunc(Of Date)()
```

Comment: This is vb.net, not vb6.

Comment: Of <Type> is a generic; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.80).aspx#Y720

Comment: It was my mistake, it should have been Date, never mind. It went wrong when I copy and pasted from a vb6 solution to a vb.net.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in a comment to your question, this is not vb6, and can never be used in vb6; it's VB.Net, which is really a whole new language.  The code uses a feature that is not available in vb6: generics.  There is nothing even close to this feature available for vb6.

In this case, `(Of Date)` is not the argument list for the function parameters.  It's the argument list for the type parameters of a generic function.  The keyword "Of" indicates it's a type list and "Date" means the type for this call will be `Date`.  The parameter argument list comes after the type argument list.  So if the function accepts a string parameter, you should call it like this:

```
myfunc(Of Date)("7/6/2011")
```

Because it's a generic function, you could also call it like this:

```
myfunc(Of Integer)("12345")
```

Though whether either of those calls has any meaning depends on the body of the function.